# If $\mu$ is a complex measure, every set $E$ has $A \subset E$ so that $|\mu(A)| \ge \frac{1}{\pi}|\mu|(E).$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

If $\mu$ is a complex measure on a $\sigma$-algebra $M$, show that every set $E \in M$ has a subset $A$ for which $$|\mu(A)| \ge \frac{1}{\pi}|\mu|(E).$$
The suggestion is as follows:
Put $d\mu=e^{i\theta}d|\mu|$.  Let $A_\alpha$ be the subset of $E$ where $cos(\theta - \alpha) > 0$.  Show that $$Re[e^{-i\alpha}\mu(A_\alpha)]=\int_Ecos^+(\theta-\alpha) d|\mu|,$$ and integrate with respect to $\alpha$.

Show, by an example, that $1/\pi$ is the best constant in this inequality.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the definitions in the hint, we have:

$$
e^{-i\alpha}\mu(A_\alpha) = \int_{E} \chi_{A_\alpha} e^{i(\theta - \alpha)}\,d|\mu|
$$

Thus:

$$
\left|\mu(A_\alpha)\right| \ge \Re\left(e^{-i\alpha}\mu(A_\alpha)\right) = \Re\left(\int_{E} \chi_{A_\alpha} e^{i(\theta - \alpha)}\,d|\mu|\right) = \int_E \cos^+(\theta-\alpha)\,d|\mu|
$$

Choose $\alpha = \alpha_0$ to maximize the integral on the RHS. The value at $a_0$ is at least as large as the average:

$$
\left|\mu(A_{\alpha_0})\right| \ge \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \int_E \cos^+(\theta-\alpha)\,d|\mu|d\alpha
$$

Use Fubini's theorem to swap integral signs on the RHS and obtain:

$$
\left|\mu(A_{\alpha_0})\right| \ge \int_E \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos^+(\theta-\alpha)\,d\alpha d|\mu|= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_E 2 \,d|\mu| = \frac{1}{\pi}|\mu|(E)
$$

---

To show that this is the best possible constant, consider the unit circle equipped with $d\mu = e^{i\theta} \, dm$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. For any measurable set $E$ and $A \subset E$, pick $\alpha$ so that $e^{-i\alpha}\mu(A) \ge 0$ (always possible). I'll let you show that $\left|\mu(A)\right| \le \frac{1}{\pi}|\mu|(E)$.

Comment: @CHG No problem. I also added an example to show that $1/\pi$ is the best possible constant.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing this question today.

---

**Fact-$1$:** (Papa Rudin Exercise $6.1$) Let $\mu$ be a complex measure. Then the total variation measure $$|\mu|(E)=\sup\{\sum_{i=1}^n|\mu(E_i)|: n\in \Bbb N, \{E_i\}_{i=1}^n \text{ is a partition of } E.\}$$
Remember that *partition* means $E_i$'s are disjoint and $\cup_{i=1}^n E_i=E$.

**Fact-$2$:** (Papa Rudin Theorem $6.12$) Let $\mu$ be a complex measure. Then there exists a measurable function $h$ such that $|h(x)|=1$ for all $x\in X$ and such that $$d\mu=hd|\mu|$$
(Here you're taking $h=e^{i\theta}$)

**Fact-$3$:** (Papa Rudin Lemma $6.3$) If $z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_N$ are complex numbers then there is a subset $S$ of $\{1,2,\ldots, N\}$  for which $$\left|\sum_{k\in S}z_k\right|\geq \frac1{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^N|z_k|$$

---

Let $E\in\mathcal M$. Now start with a partition $\{E_i\}_{i=1}^n$ of $E$. Then by fact-3, there exists a subset $S$ of $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$  such that $$\left|\sum_{k\in S}\mu(E_k)\right|\geq \frac1{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^n|\mu(E_k)|=\frac1{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^n|\mu|(E_k)=\frac1{\pi}|\mu|(E).$$ First equality is because of fact-2 and last equality is because $|\mu|$ is a measure. Now take $A=\cup_{k\in S}E_k$. Since $E_k$'s are disjoint and $\mu$ is a complex measure so $\mu(A)=\sum_{k\in S}\mu(E_k)$.
Hence, $$|\mu(A)|\geq \frac1{\pi}|\mu|(E)$$

---

To see that $\frac1{\pi}$ is best possible see the following papers:
[Biedsoe-AMM](https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.1970.11992451) and [Kaufmann-Rickert-Bull. Am. Math.](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1966-72-04/S0002-9904-1966-11551-3/S0002-9904-1966-11551-3.pdf)

Comment: Now that I see @Ayman's proof, my proof is exactly the same proof. I just skipped the "main" proof by referring to the known theorem. In fact, the way Ayman proves is the same way you prove fact-3. Should I delete my answer?